# macOS: Embedding OpenJDK 11 in application still raises java 6 alert

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface

We are having a cross platform application that consists of a java swing UI and a lot of native code. Java and native code talk to each other using JNI. We compile and link against java 11. This works nicely on windows and linux.

On mac we presently have used the old Apple Java 6. We want to get rid of this dependancy and where moving to openJDK 11 on all platforms. Everything appears to run fine. We see that our application is launching our embedded java 11 version and that some java code already gets executed but after some very short time the Apple "please install Java SE 6" alert pops up.

How can this be prevented? When Apple java is installed the application works and works using java 11 not java 6.

What is macOS checking here - why does it think java 6 is still needed?

We locate the java 11 version we have embedded with our native code and load the jvm dylib dynamically and finally call JNI_CreateJVM() to instantiate a jvm and then we jump into some java code which starts to get executed but after some time the dreaded "Please install Java SE 6 alert" pops up.

I am testing with macOS Sierra/High Sierra and Mojave.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you uninstall Java 6 completely prior installing OpenJDK 11?

Comment: There was never java 6 on these 3 systems I am using. openjdk 11 is not installed on the system but delivered somewhere inside of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you need to load libjli.dylib instead of libjvm.dylib to avoid the Java 6 alert on macOS.